# Can I use f:convertNumber with h:outputFormat

Tags: java, jsf, outputformat

I have a composite component and this is a snippet from it.

```html
<h:outputFormat id="output" value="{0} / {1} / {2}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.readOnly}" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value1 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value1}" />
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value2 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value2}" />
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value3 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value3}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

If I want to format value3 using `<f:convertNumber>`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<h:outputFormat>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputFormat.html) uses under the covers standard [`java.text.MessageFormat` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). Go ahead clicking that link and reading the javadoc.

[`<f:convertNumber>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertNumber.html) uses under the covers the standard [`java.text.NumberFormat` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) which happens to be supported by `MessageFormat` as well. As its javadoc says, numeric patterns can be represented by `{[index], number, [pattern]}`.

Thus, so (this example assumes that you want 2 fixed-length fraction digits):

```html
<h:outputFormat id="output" value="{0} / {1} / {2,number,#.00}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.readOnly}" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value1 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value1}" />
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value2 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value2}" />
    <f:param value="#{empty cc.attrs.value3 ? '-' : cc.attrs.value3}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: That is a great piece of information you give me here, but unfortunately I was to use the grouping property of the convertNumber. Is that possible ?

Comment: Just add/remove `,` if necessary to enable/disable grouping.

Comment: your answered helped me to develop my answer, unfrotunately i get an exception when I do that. The solution was to make the same check in the value of the outputformat and choose between "number" or simply empty