# How to override JSF outputFormat locale

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, internationalization

Suppose I have code like this:

```
<h:outputFormat value="The number is {0, number, #.##}">
  <f:param value="#{bean.double}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

From my understanding, JSF uses `MessageFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)` method to convert the value. So if my locale is Spanish, and bean.double is `3.72`, then the result will be `3,72` even if my `SubformatPattern` is `#.##`.

Is there a way to format the number as `3.72` and keep the locale as Spanish?

FYI, I set the locale by using the `f:view` element with a locale attribute — for example:

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}"/>
```

Reference:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html
- [Can I use f:convertNumber with h:outputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965033/can-i-use-fconvertnumber-with-houtputformat)

Answer (score 0):

You could by [overriding the renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605401/jsf-2-0-how-to-override-base-renderers-with-custom-ones) for the `outputFormat` tag.

Have a look at the [Mojarra source for `OutputMessageRenderer`](https://java.net/projects/mojarra/sources/svn/content/trunk/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/OutputMessageRenderer.java). Find this statement:

```
MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat(currentValue,
                                      context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
```

In this statement hardcode the locale to English and you are done.

The easy way would be to simply format your number in your bean using a hardcoded locale and return it as a string, so you can simply use:

```
<h:outputFormat value="The number is {0}">
  <f:param value="#{bean.formatDouble(bean.double)}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

See also:

- [How to override h:selectOneRadio renderer? Where is the renderer class in jsf-impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389352/how-to-override-hselectoneradio-renderer-where-is-the-renderer-class-in-jsf-im)